# Calculating change of basis with non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

"Let $P$ be the plane $2x-2y-z=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We know that P is a 2-dimensional vector space with basis
$$\mathcal{B}=\{v_1=(1,0,2),v_2=(1,1,0)\}.$$
Now introduce $\mathcal{A}$ which is also a basis of $P$ with
$\mathcal{A}=\{w_1=(1,2,-2),w_2=(2,1,2)\}.$

Calculate the change of basis matrix $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}).$"

Usually in class we would define $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{B})$, which is easy enough, but then we would take $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ to be equal to $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{A})^{-1}\cdot\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{B})$ which I can't do given that $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{A})$ isn't square.

How should this question be approached?